# Exploring the Concept of Gradient Flow

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, gradient-descent

Understanding the concept of "Gradient Flow" can be quite difficult as there is a lack of widely recognized and clearly defined resources that provide a comprehensive explanation. Although you can find insights from machine learning experts and references to papers that mention gradient flow, there isn't a single, definitive source that thoroughly covers the topic.

Could you please recommend a resource that offers a detailed understanding of gradient flow? Your assistance is greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gradient-flows